# What exactly does % do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert some JavaScript code into Java, but I do not know what the `%` character between two numeric variables does:

```
    testvalue = somevalue%anothervalue;
```

What does this mean or what would the same statement be in Java?

I also have this in JavaScript:

```
    if(somevalue%2 == 1){
    }
```

What does `%2` mean here?

Comment: @jlordo, it seems he is translating from one to another. I do not think there is any confusion.

Comment: And I believe it is the modulo operator OP.

Comment: 5%2 is 1. It gives remainder.

Comment: @jsn: I was too quick. Should have read more carefully.

Comment: Have you searched for JavaScript math operators?  I recently needed to know if JS had this operator an that search gave me very straightforward results.  I won't answer, however, because I think there's a good fish vs fishing opportunity here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the **[modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29)**.

This returns "the first operand modulo the second operand", which is the remainder when you substract (or add) as much of the second operand off/to of the first, to get as close as possible to 0.

Here's an example:

```
 5  % 2 ==  1  ( 5  = 2*2   +1)
 6  % 2 ==  0  ( 6  = 2*3   +0)
 12 % 5 ==  2  ( 12 = 5*2   +2)
-5  % 2 == -1  (-5  = 2*-2  -1)
-6  % 2 ==  0  (-6  = 2*-3  -0)
-12 % 5 == -2  (-12 = 5*-2  -2)
//                           ^ That's the result of the modulo.
```

Comment: your description does not make sense for negative numbers.

Comment: @Alex: And "Division remainder" does? `5 / 2 == 2.5`. The other answers aren't any less vague than mine was. Any way, edited.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [modulus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.100).aspx) operator. The modulus operator performs division on the two values and gives you the remainder as the output.

For example:

```
var testValue = 5 % 3;
```

testValue output would be 2

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have updated the link, and with your rep, you could have easily done it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is the modulo operator. It gives you the remainder of `somevalue/anothervalue`, i.e. `10%4 === 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the modulo operator in both Java and JavaScript and other programming languages.

It returns the remainder of a division, e.g.,

```
5 % 2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's "modulus" or remainder division - in other words, returning the remainder of the division.

See this page on [JavaScript Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It performs a modulo calcuation. That is: determining the [divison reminder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). And yes, Java uses the same syntax for this.

Example: 5%3 = 2

Because 3 goes into 5 once, and there is a reminder of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
X%5
```

means the remaining of x/5 so if x=12 then x%5 = 2
if you want to increase a number in a loop up to a maximum

```
<button onclick="incX();">increase up to 5</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x=0;
    function incX(){
        x%=5;
        x++;
        alert("X = "+x);
    }
</script>
```